# Conflict: kluwer and amsmath

Tags: amsmath, incompatibility

When I try to use the document class `kluwer` together with `amsmath` there seems to be a conflict. Is is possible to avoid this conflict?

I have tried to add `\let\iint\noexists` before loading `amsmath` as suggested in http://groups.google.com/group/comp.text.tex/browse_thread/thread/b57ac7fcbffa5120/9afe4da0cacfffdf but that doesn't help.

Here's an example. The following

```
\documentclass{kluwer}

%\let\iint\noexists 
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Bla bla bla

\end{document}
```

gives the following error

```
ERROR: LaTeX Error: Command `\iint` already defined.
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For me, a minor modification of the linked fix works:

```
\documentclass{kluwer}

\let\iint\undefined 
\let\iiint\undefined 
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Bla bla bla

\end{document}
```

You need to undefine both `\iint` and `\iiint` (count the `i`s!)